# How can I call a function that set sets an outside variable inside a custom component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still new to React but as I'm learning I'm trying to create reusable components. I'm stuck on a radio group. I have everything except for extracting the key from the component to a variable inside my normal code.

My component looks as follows:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import * as colors from "../defines/js_colors"

import RN_button from "./RN_button"

function RN_radioGroup(props) {
  const [radioSelect, setRadioSelect] = useState("RN_button")
  // useEffect(() => {}, [radioSelect])

  return (
    <View>
      {props.radioGroupList.map((item) => {
        return (
          <View key={item.key}>
            <RN_button
              buttonText={item.label}
              darkBackgroundColor={radioSelect == item.key ? colors.white : "transparent"}
              darkBorderColor={colors.white}
              darkTextFontColor={colors.textLightBlue}
              // onPress = data => setState({ radioSelect });
              onPress={() => {
                setRadioSelect(item.key)
              }}
            />
          </View>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
}

RN_radioGroup.propTypes = {
  radioGroupList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

export default RN_radioGroup
```

RN_button is custom button component, but doesn't really matter here.
radioGroupList is an array with a key and a label that I pass as a prop and colors contains definitions of different colors.

```
function screen({navigation}) {
  const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState("NULL")
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RN_radioGroup radioGroupList={arrays.radioGroup1} onPress={radioValue} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I need to use the selected key value that is in the radio group outside on the screen.
The screen code is stripped down to just the basics that is required, but the radio group class is exactly as shown.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to virtually anything in react, is usually one of two things:

1. Don't mutate state (not applicable here).
2. Lift state up (the answer here).

You need to put the selected value up to a common ancestor of the `screen` and `RN_radioGroup` component - putting it as state in the `screen` component seems like it will be sufficient.

Don't have `[radioSelect,setRadioSelect]` as part of the `RN_radioGroup` state, instead pass it in as a prop.

It'll look something like this where you pass in a prop of `selected` to `RN_radioGroup` which will be the chosen value.

```js
function screen({navigation}) {
  const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState("NULL")
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RN_radioGroup radioGroupList={arrays.radioGroup1} selected={radioValue} onPress={setRadioValue} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

// RN_radioGroup

function RN_radioGroup(props) {
  // the selected value, and the update function are now passed in as props 
  const { selected, onPress, radioGroupList } = props;

  return (
    <View>
      {radioGroupList.map((item) => {
        return (
          <View key={item.key}>
            <RN_button
              buttonText={item.label}
              darkBackgroundColor={radioSelect == item.key ? colors.white : "transparent"}
              darkBorderColor={colors.white}
              darkTextFontColor={colors.textLightBlue}
              { /* onPress, call the updater function, which I've also coincidentally named onPress */ }
              onPress={() => onPress(item.key)}
            />
          </View>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I understand the idea you're explaining here, but I have no idea how to implement it. I saw some examples of lifting the state, they look completely different to my implementation. Whenever I try to implement it, I get an error saying that I can't "update a component from inside the function bod of different component". Can you please give me an example of what to do inside the radio group class, or even just point me to a good example that explains this type of implementation. And thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @HeinK seem my edit to see if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is you lift the state up, which mean you should put the `[radioSelect,setRadioSelect]` way up in the component that contains `RN_radioGroup`

somehow like this

```js
// my screen
function screen({navigation}) {
  const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState("NULL")
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RN_radioGroup 
          radioGroupList={arrays.radioGroup1} 
          selected={radioValue} 
          onSelect={setRadioValue} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

// your RN_radioGroup

function RN_radioGroup(props) {
  // you destructure the props to get these values
  // you use these to change the selected value
  const {selected, onSelect} = props;

  return (
    <View>
      {props.radioGroupList.map((item) => {
        return (
          <View key={item.key}>
            <RN_button
              buttonText={item.label}

              // you compare the value if it is selected here
              darkBackgroundColor={selected == item.key ? colors.white : "transparent"}
              darkBorderColor={colors.white}
              darkTextFontColor={colors.textLightBlue}
              onPress={() => {
                onSelect(item.key)
              }}
            />
          </View>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Adam edited his previous comment and you both advised me on the same thing, but I still appreciate the answer.